# How does one access Team Foundation Server from an iDevice?

Tags: iphone, ios

Sometimes I need to access a document from TFS on my iPhone/iPad (for example, in a meeting), but the web interface is so clunky, it's nearly impossible.  Specifically, I can't bring up any attachments.

Is there an iDevice client that has been known to work well?  I've seen 2 on the App Store but couldn't make either one work.

Comment: I assume TFS refers to Team Foundation Server. It's an unusual acronym around here so it might be good to edit and clarify that.